# Count of unique hosts associated to groups that accounts have access to

Tags: vba, excel, performance

I'm sure this is a really easy problem to fix. I currently have a excel spreadsheet with two sheets. The first is a sheet with accounts in column A, a space for the number of hosts in Column B and then the rest of the columns to the right are the groups that the account has access to. In the other sheet I have 2 columns of data, the first column is the host and the second column is the group.  I am trying to get a count of the number of hosts associated with a given account for each account in the first sheet.

Since The hosts can be in multiple groups and the account can be associated with multiple groups there can be duplicate hosts counted for an account. I tried to create a macro that would loop through the first sheet get the value of the group and then go to the second sheet and put all of the host names for that group into an array. It would do it for each group and add the hosts to the end of the array until it reach the end of the group list for a given account. my macro then uses a function to remove the duplicates from the array and then put the count of the array into the cell in column b on sheet 1.

To make this array I have been putting bits and pieces together from stuff I found on this site but I think I have something messed up. The macro ends up putting the same number in column b no matter which groups are associated with the account.

My code is below:

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable()
'PURPOSE: Dynamically Create Array Variable based on a Given Size

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim myString As String
Dim x As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim d As Variant
Dim row As Integer
Dim Group As String
Dim endRow As Long

For i = 2 To 5
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:I2").Cells 'Finds the group the account belongs to and loops through each of them
    'For c = 3 To 8

    Group = c.Value

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

    endRow = 14 ' of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
        For r = 1 To endRow

            If Cells(r, Columns("B").Column).Value = Group Then 'adds each host in the group into an array

            myString = myString & ";|;" & Cells(r, 1).Value

            End If

        Next r
    Next 'c

'Remove first delimiter from string (;|;)
   myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 3)


'Create an array with the Split() function
    myArray = Split(myString, ";|;")

arr2 = RemoveDupesColl(myArray)

Dim lNumElements As Long

    lNumElements = UBound(arr2) - LBound(arr2) + 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = lNumElements
myString = Empty

Next i

'Print values to Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
     'For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
      '   Debug.Print myArray(x)
       '  Next x

End Sub
```

and here is the remove duplicates function:

```
Function RemoveDupesColl(myArray As Variant) As Variant
'DESCRIPTION:  Removes duplicates from your array using the collection method.
'NOTES:  (1)   This function returns unique elements in your array, but
'              it converts your array elements to strings.
'SOURCE: https://wellsr.com
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrColl As New Collection
    Dim arrDummy() As Variant
    Dim arrDummy1() As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    ReDim arrDummy1(LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray))

    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) 'convert to string
        arrDummy1(i) = CStr(myArray(i))
    Next i
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each item In arrDummy1
       arrColl.Add item, item
    Next item
    Err.Clear
    ReDim arrDummy(LBound(myArray) To arrColl.Count - LBound(myArray) - 1)
    i = LBound(myArray)
    For Each item In arrColl
       arrDummy(i) = item
       i = i + 1
    Next item
    RemoveDupesColl = arrDummy
End Function
```

Could someone help me figure out how to make this work or help me with a more efficient macro since I will eventually be using this for a couple thousand of accounts, over 100 groups and over 10000 hosts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This stores the count of unique Hosts per Group from `Sheet2` (nesting shown bellow)

The main operation generates a set of unique Hosts for all Groups, on the same row (record)

It expects the first row as Header in both sheets, and Groups to start in column `C` on `Sheet1`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateHosts()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = Sheet1    'Or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = Sheet2
    Dim lr1 As Long:        lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lc1 As Long:        lc1 = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim lr2 As Long:        lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim groups As Object:   Set groups = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, arr As Variant, h As String, g As String, hosts As Object

    arr = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(lr2, 2))             'Sheet2 - Hosts
    For r = 2 To lr2                'Exclude Headers
        h = arr(r, 1)               'Convert host to string (number to string)
        g = arr(r, 2)               'Convert group to string (number to string)
        If Not groups.Exists(g) Then
            Set hosts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            hosts(h) = 0
            Set groups(g) = hosts
        Else
            groups(g)(h) = 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim itm As Variant, u As Object

    arr = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, lc1)).Formula   'Sheet1 - Accounts
    For r = 2 To lr1                'Exclude Headers
        Set u = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For c = 3 To lc1
            g = arr(r, c)           'Convert any group (number to string)
            If groups.Exists(g) Then
                For Each itm In groups(g)
                    u(itm) = 0      'Extract unique hosts for all groups in this row
                Next
            End If
        Next
        arr(r, 2) = u.Count
    Next
    ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, lc1)).Formula = arr
End Sub
```

---

.

Performance

```
ws1.Rows (Accounts): 10,001
ws2.Rows (Hosts):   100,002 (Groups: 10,000)
Time:   2.238 sec
```

---

.

Nested dictionaries - structure (keys only):

```
Group: 1 -> Host: H2      (not unique in set: Group 1 + Group 4)
Group: 1 -> Host: H5      (not unique in set: Group 1 + Group 4)
Group: 1 -> Host: H10002
Group: 1 -> Host: H20002
Group: 1 -> Host: H30002
...
Group: 1 -> Host: H90002

Group: 2 -> Host: H3      (not unique in set: Group 2 + Group 3)
Group: 2 -> Host: H4      (not unique in set: Group 2 + Group 3)
Group: 2 -> Host: H10003
Group: 2 -> Host: H20003
Group: 2 -> Host: H30003
...
Group: 2 -> Host: H90003

Group: 3 -> Host: H4      (not unique in set: Group 2 + Group 3)
Group: 3 -> Host: H3      (not unique in set: Group 2 + Group 3)
Group: 3 -> Host: H10004
Group: 3 -> Host: H20004
Group: 3 -> Host: H30004
...
Group: 3 -> Host: H90004

Group: 4 -> Host: H5      (not unique in set: Group 1 + Group 4)
Group: 4 -> Host: H2      (not unique in set: Group 1 + Group 4)
...
```

---

Test Data

**`Sheet1`**

[image: Sheet1]

**`Sheet2`**

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I may have not explained it correctly but the main problem im trying to solve is that an account can have access to multiple groups which have access to hosts that can be in multiple groups for example A and B and groups A could haves access to hosts 1, 2 and 3 and B could have access to 2, 3, 4. What im trying to do it get a count of all unique hosts the account has access to. Your solution would give me an answer of 6 cause its unique hosts within groups but the correct answer to what I need would be 4 since 2 and 3 were repeated. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @Tim - The explanation and test would be easier if you can provide a small sample of test data for `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. I updated the initial version - let me know if it works as expected